# How to define dynamically registered Vue so they are recognized in the IDE

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ide, webstorm, vite

I wrote this neat script that registers all Vue components inside a folder so I don't have to import them manually everywhere since they have a really common usage inside the project.

```
import { App } from '@vue/runtime-core'

export function registerGlobalComponents(app: App<Element>) {
    const components = import.meta.globEager('../../views/components/*.vue')

    Object.entries(components).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
        const componentName = path
            .split('/')
            .pop()
            ?.replace(/\.\w+$/, '')

        if (typeof componentName === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error(`Could not extract component name from path: ${path}`)
        }

        app.component(componentName, definition.default)
    })

    return app
}
```

I want to be able to tell my IDE (PHPStorm/WebStorm/VSCode) to recognize these dynamically registered components. BTW I'm using Vite with TypeScript.